# How to Intelligently Sample Parameter Space while Training a Statistical Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm interested in a statistical classification problem.  Given a feature vector X, I would like to classify X as either "yes" or "no".  However, the training data will be fed in real-time based on human input.  For instance, if the user sees feature vector X, the user will assign "yes" or "no" based on their expertise.

Rather than doing grid search on parameter space, I would like to more intelligently explore the parameter space based on the previously submitted data.  For example, if there is a dense cluster of "no's" in part of the parameter space, it probably doesn't make sense to keep sampling there - it's probably just going to be more "no's".

How can I go about doing this?  The [C4.5 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm) seems to be up this alley, but I'm unsure if this is the way to go.

An additional subtlety is that some of the features might be specifying random data.  Suppose that the first two attributes in the feature vector specify the mean and variance of a gaussian distribution.  The data the user classifies could be significantly different, even if all parameters are held equal.

For example, let's say the algorithm displays a sine wave with gaussian noise added, where the gaussian distribution is specified by the mean and variance in the feature vector.  The user is asked "does this graph represent a sine wave?"  Two very similar values in mean or variance could still have significantly different graphs.

Is there an algorithm designed to handle such cases?

Comment: This is a classic example of the exploration vs. exploitation problem (often) analyzed by bandit-theory. The common (huge) ML-area tackling these is Reinforcement-learning. (Your example does not look promising but i don't know much about it; it just looks like an algorithm for supervised-learning to me). Given the information in this question, there is not much else to advice. Every approach will heavily dependen on your model (no gain without some assumptions) and maybe grid-search / or random-search is hard to beat (without weeks of tuning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting that you're talking about fits in the broad area of [Active Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning)). This topic addresses the iterative process of model building, and choosing which training examples to query next in order to optimize model performance. Here, the training cost of each data point is roughly the same, and there are no additional variable rewards in the learning phase.

However, in each iteration, if you have a variable reward which is a function of the data point chosen, you would want to look at [Multi-Armed Bandits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) and [Reinforcement Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning).

The other issue that you're talking about is one of finding the right features to represent your data points, and should be handled separately.

Comment: "Active Learning" was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!